# Me genero un TypeError at / en mi proyecto django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Según el error indicó la ruta de origen donde se ha producido: AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py
Explícitamente en la línea 255 en la función de blind_template.

Este es la función extraída del archivo de context.py:

```
def bind_template(self, template):
    if self.template is not None:
        raise RuntimeError("Context is already bound to a template")

    self.template = template
    # Set context processors according to the template engine's settings.
    processors = template.engine.template_context_processors + self._processors
    updates = {}
    for processor in processors:
        updates.update(processor(self.request))
    self.dicts[self._processors_index] = updates

    try:
        yield
    finally:
        self.template = None
        # Unset context processors.
        self.dicts[self._processors_index] = {}
```

Comment: Hola Kris, esta es la zona de respuestas, y has publicado de nuevo tu consulta en ella, te sugiero que elimines esta publicación para evitar recibir votos negativos.

Comment: Podrías poner el código donde haces referencia a tu template, es decir, la que origina que entre a este error.